# FOSUser email confirmation is not working

Tags: php, symfony, email, fosuserbundle

I am trying send confirmation email to user after registration. I customised email template, so that user can receive email with confirmation url in it.

These are my configurations

```
fos_user:
  # ...
  service:
      mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
  registration:
      confirmation:
          template: AppBundle:Email:registration.email.twig
          from_email:
              address:        registration@example.com
              sender_name:    Example
```

This is my template

```
  {% block subject %}Registration Success{% endblock %}

  {% block body_text %}
     {% autoescape false %}
         Hello {{ user.fullName }}!

         Thanks for registering

         <p><a href="{{ confirmationUrl }}">verify</a></p>

         Greetings,
         CofiCo team
    {% endautoescape %}

 {% endblock %}
```

I am triggering email sending in my controller manually:

```
$token = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$user->setConfirmationToken($token);
$this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);
```

The email is not sending with this template. However If I remove `{{ confirmationUrl }}` from template, email send works fine.

How can I send email with confirmation URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. Everything works, except emails with absolute URLs were going to spam folder. setting mail encryption solved this problem